# Validation disappears on autopostback

Tags: javascript, asp.net, validation

I am validating my control using javascript function. I cannot use validators available in asp. It s working fine but when radio button postback then rest of the validation disappear. ***Here is my Validation code***

```
 function ValidateForm() {
                var validate = true;                
         var summary = document.getElementById("<%=summary.ClientID%>");
                if (summary.value == "") {
                    summary.style.backgroundColor = "Yellow";
                    validate = false;
                }
                if (validate == false) {
                    alert('Please fill highlighted fields');
                }
                return validate;
```

***here is button code which validate***

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" OnClick="Button1_Click" Text="Submit" OnClientClick="return ValidateForm();" />
```

***Here is my radio button code***

```
<asp:RadioButton ID="Submitter" Text="Submitter" GroupName="rd2" runat="server" ForeColor="Black" OnCheckedChanged="submitter_changed" AutoPostBack="true" />
                        <asp:RadioButton ID="Following" Text="Following" GroupName="rd2" runat="server" ForeColor="Black" OnCheckedChanged="following_changed" AutoPostBack="true" />
```

I want color will not change after *autopostback*. help me please how to do it.

Comment: Found the solution to the problem?

Comment: @Frost_Mourne I am writting javascript function to enable and disable fields on selection so then no need for autopostback

Comment: Seems sorted out then..

Comment: yes. but thank you for your help

Comment: Ya sure you are welcome .

Answer (score 1):

try using UpdatePanel like this

```
 <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:RadioButton ID="Submitter" Text="Submitter" GroupName="rd2" runat="server" ForeColor="Black" OnCheckedChanged="submitter_changed" AutoPostBack="true" />
        <asp:RadioButton ID="Following" Text="Following" GroupName="rd2" runat="server" ForeColor="Black" OnCheckedChanged="following_changed" AutoPostBack="true" />
   </ContentTemplate>
  </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Comment: Tried it. but same problem

Comment: UpdateMode=conditional?

Comment: its working. but ***autopostback*** is not working. which prevents my work

Comment: what happnes when autoPostback happens?

Comment: textboxes enable and disable

Comment: put the TexBoxes inside the UpdatePanel too & then try,( everything related to that post back put it in UpdatePanel)

Comment: U might need to toggle the UpdateMode with that... try and let me know..:)

Comment: Ok. I am trying

Comment: Use UpdateMode=Conditional & in c# u can use UpdatePanel(idname here).Update();

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150074/discussion-between-rami-far-and-frost-mourne).